# Join certain rows to the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a query that will call get all that matches `col3 = 1` and get the rest of the group `col4 = 123` while having col2 be the distinct value. My table looks like

```
ID  col1    col2    col3    col4
---------------------------------
1   A1      A       NULL    123
2   B1      B       NULL    123
3   C1      C       NULL    123
4   D1      D       NULL    123
5   C2      C       1       123
6   D2      D       1       123
```

and I am trying to make a query that would return IDs 1,2,5 and 6. Have tried unions and joins off variations of `select * from tbl where col4 = 123 and col3 =1` and they all either exclude 3,4,5,6 or include them all.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What criteria do you want to use to select rows?

Comment: I basically want to query for col4 = 123 and then get everything that has a value in col 3 and all the other values that don't match col2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      *


from       (select      *

                       ,row_number () over
                        (
                            partition by    col2
                            order by        case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 2 end
                        ) as rn

            from        t

            where       col4 = 123
            ) t

where       col3 = 1
        or  t.rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows where `col3` is not `NULL` and then of the remaining rows, those that have different `col2` values from those:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col4 = 123 and
      (t.col3 is not null or
       t.col2 not in (select t.col2 from t t2 where t2.col4 = 123 and t2.col3 is not null)
      )
```

Comment: Don't forget the "col4 = 123" requirement

Comment: I think the "123" requirement should only apply to the second part (when t.col3 is null)